# Can a Backgroundworker proceed working when it reaches the "...Completed" event handler

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

as described in the title. My backgroundworker is doing its job...finishes the first
part and calls the ...Completed event handler. Can I tell here my backgroundworker to proceed with another job by doing 
DoWork -= OldJob 
DoWork += NewJob

also
DoWorkCompleted -= OldJobCompleted
DoWorkCompleted += NewJobCompleted

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can restart it after it has completed. And you could plug in another DoWork first.

**But you shouldn't.**

A BGW executes on the ThreadPool, so this is not necessary to re-use the Thread.  So avoid the mess and just create separate Backgroundworkers for distinct tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it before, but I guess it would work. Wouldn't you need to change the event handler for [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) too?

I think it would be a lot simpler just to create two background workers instead. Or if the jobs are very similar you could parameterize your existing background worker to be able to do both tasks.